# Should I Install a sub-panel, IN PLACE OF of an unused hot tub disconnect, for a basement project, and will I need to change the main breaker?

Tags: electrical-panel, basement, subpanel

I have removed the hot tub disconnect and pulled the 4 wire (6G)  back into the basement.  This line comes from the main breaker panel on a 2-pole 50A breaker. My plan is to instal a basement sub-panel and feed it using the this former hot tub line.  The sub-panel is to have 2x 120V, 15A circuits, to be used for a basement brewery  project.  From what I read in this forum, it appears a sub-panel is appropriate.  I only need two 120V Circuits, and think that each would get their own hot wire from the old line, and share N and G.  Planning for the  sub-panel breakers to be 15A single pole, with 14Gauge wiring to the respective outlets.   Since the sub panel has 15A breakers protecting their lines, and since the wire between the main and the sub-panel are 6 Gauge, is there any need to replace the 2-pole 30A breaker in the main ?  And, is the plan okay as stated?

Comment: Looks mostly good, but in your 2nd to last sentence you mention a 30 amp breaker, did you mean the original 50 amp breaker? Breakers are meant to protect the wiring, not equipment, so using the original 50 amp breaker on 6 ga wire is totally appropriate.

Comment: One more comment: Unless your brewing equipment specifically calls for a 15 amp circuit, I'd go 20 amp, minor  cost increase in wiring.  As others have said here, go bigger on the sub panel that you think you need, it's cheap insurance for future needs. And in a sub, you need to separate the neutral from the ground when you wire it up.  Since you already have a 4 wire feed, that should be easy.

Comment: If there is a compatible two pole AFCI breaker for your panel for now you could skip mounting a subpanel and just replace the breaker in the existing panel. You could always add a panel later if needed. Don't neglect current NEC requires both AFCI and GFCI protection in your basement.

Comment: Thanks George, typo on my part, is 50A breaker at main panel, not 30A.  And I will go with 20A circuit vs 15A, good suggestion. N&G separation is planned.

Comment: NoSparksPlease,  glad you pointed out new code requirements re: AFCI as I was unaware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your logic.